# Struggling to point my form to a view with a variable in Django

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Error: NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'language' with keyword arguments '{'name': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[^/]+)/\Z']

I am creating a Encyclopedia app in Django which has a form as a input, which will display the search result from my view after searching those input variable in util.py file.

I have created a form like below in my template

```
<form method="get" formaction="{% url 'language' name=form.name%}">
    <input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia
</form>
```

Here goes my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<str:name>/", views.language, name="language"),
]
```

And the language function in views.py(not writing whole views.py as it will take a lot of space here):

```
def language(request, name):
    if util.get_entry(name):
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/entries.html",{
            "entries": util.get_entry(name),
            "title": name.capitalize()
            })
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound("<div style='text-align:center;font-          family:sans-serif'><h1>Error</h1><h2> Requested page was not found.</h2></div>")
```

Answer (score 0):

form.name is empty. You have "entries" and "title" in the rendering context but not form.name